# Don't know how to build task 'routes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't execute `rake routes` even if the `routes.rb` file is empty. This is the output:

```
➜ rake routes
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'routes' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Output from `rake about`:

```
➜ rake about
About your application's environment
Rails version             6.1.0
Ruby version              ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-darwin19]
RubyGems version          3.1.4
Rack version              2.2.3
Middleware                Webpacker::DevServerProxy, Rack::MiniProfiler, ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization, Rack::Sendfile, ActionDispatch::Static, ActionDispatch::Executor, ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware, Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, Sprockets::Rails::QuietAssets, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, WebConsole::Middleware, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::ActionableExceptions, ActionDispatch::Reloader, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ContentSecurityPolicy::Middleware, ActionDispatch::PermissionsPolicy::Middleware, Rack::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag, Rack::TempfileReaper, Warden::Manager
Application root          /Users/cobexa/app
Environment               development
Database adapter          postgresql
Database schema version   20201219225707
```

And output from `rake --tasks`:

```
rake about                              # List versions of all Rails frameworks and the environment
rake action_mailbox:ingress:exim        # Relay an inbound email from Exim to Action Mailbox (URL and INGRESS_PASSWORD required)
rake action_mailbox:ingress:postfix     # Relay an inbound email from Postfix to Action Mailbox (URL and INGRESS_PASSWORD required)
rake action_mailbox:ingress:qmail       # Relay an inbound email from Qmail to Action Mailbox (URL and INGRESS_PASSWORD required)
rake action_mailbox:install             # Installs Action Mailbox and its dependencies
rake action_mailbox:install:migrations  # Copy migrations from action_mailbox to application
rake action_text:install                # Copy over the migration, stylesheet, and JavaScript files
rake action_text:install:migrations     # Copy migrations from action_text to application
rake active_storage:install             # Copy over the migration needed to the application
rake app:template                       # Applies the template supplied by LOCATION=(/path/to/template) or URL
rake app:update                         # Update configs and some other initially generated files (or use just update:configs or update:bin)
rake assets:clean[keep]                 # Remove old compiled assets
rake assets:clobber                     # Remove compiled assets
rake assets:environment                 # Load asset compile environment
rake assets:precompile                  # Compile all the assets named in config.assets.precompile
rake cache_digests:dependencies         # Lookup first-level dependencies for TEMPLATE (like messages/show or comments/_comment.html)
rake cache_digests:nested_dependencies  # Lookup nested dependencies for TEMPLATE (like messages/show or comments/_comment.html)
rake db:create                          # Creates the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the current RAILS_ENV (use db:create:all to create all databases in the config). Without RAILS_ENV or when RAILS_ENV is development, it defaults to creating the development and test databases, except when DATABASE_URL is present
rake db:drop                            # Drops the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the current RAILS_ENV (use db:drop:all to drop all databases in the config). Without RAILS_ENV or when RAILS_ENV is development, it defaults to dropping the development and test databases, except when DATABASE_URL is present
rake db:environment:set                 # Set the environment value for the database
rake db:fixtures:load                   # Loads fixtures into the current environment's database
rake db:migrate                         # Migrate the database (options: VERSION=x, VERBOSE=false, SCOPE=blog)
rake db:migrate:down                    # Runs the "down" for a given migration VERSION
rake db:migrate:redo                    # Rolls back the database one migration and re-migrates up (options: STEP=x, VERSION=x)
rake db:migrate:status                  # Display status of migrations
rake db:migrate:up                      # Runs the "up" for a given migration VERSION
rake db:prepare                         # Runs setup if database does not exist, or runs migrations if it does
rake db:reset                           # Drops and recreates the database from db/schema.rb for the current environment and loads the seeds
rake db:rollback                        # Rolls the schema back to the previous version (specify steps w/ STEP=n)
rake db:schema:cache:clear              # Clears a db/schema_cache.yml file
rake db:schema:cache:dump               # Creates a db/schema_cache.yml file
rake db:schema:dump                     # Creates a database schema file (either db/schema.rb or db/structure.sql, depending on `config.active_record.schema_format`)
rake db:schema:load                     # Loads a database schema file (either db/schema.rb or db/structure.sql, depending on `config.active_record.schema_format`) into the database
rake db:seed                            # Loads the seed data from db/seeds.rb
rake db:seed:replant                    # Truncates tables of each database for current environment and loads the seeds
rake db:setup                           # Creates the database, loads the schema, and initializes with the seed data (use db:reset to also drop the database first)
rake db:structure:dump                  # Dumps the database structure to db/structure.sql
rake db:structure:load                  # Recreates the databases from the structure.sql file
rake db:version                         # Retrieves the current schema version number
rake log:clear                          # Truncates all/specified *.log files in log/ to zero bytes (specify which logs with LOGS=test,development)
rake middleware                         # Prints out your Rack middleware stack
rake restart                            # Restart app by touching tmp/restart.txt
rake secret                             # Generate a cryptographically secure secret key (this is typically used to generate a secret for cookie sessions)
rake stats                              # Report code statistics (KLOCs, etc) from the application or engine
rake test                               # Runs all tests in test folder except system ones
rake test:all                           # Runs all tests, including system tests
rake test:db                            # Run tests quickly, but also reset db
rake test:system                        # Run system tests only
rake time:zones[country_or_offset]      # List all time zones, list by two-letter country code (`bin/rails time:zones[US]`), or list by UTC offset (`bin/rails time:zones[-8]`)
rake tmp:clear                          # Clear cache, socket and screenshot files from tmp/ (narrow w/ tmp:cache:clear, tmp:sockets:clear, tmp:screenshots:clear)
rake tmp:create                         # Creates tmp directories for cache, sockets, and pids
rake webpacker                          # Lists all available tasks in Webpacker
rake webpacker:binstubs                 # Installs Webpacker binstubs in this application
rake webpacker:check_binstubs           # Verifies that webpack & webpack-dev-server are present
rake webpacker:check_node               # Verifies if Node.js is installed
rake webpacker:check_yarn               # Verifies if Yarn is installed
rake webpacker:clean[keep,age]          # Remove old compiled webpacks
rake webpacker:clobber                  # Remove the webpack compiled output directory
rake webpacker:compile                  # Compile JavaScript packs using webpack for production with digests
rake webpacker:info                     # Provide information on Webpacker's environment
rake webpacker:install                  # Install Webpacker in this application
rake webpacker:install:angular          # Install everything needed for Angular
rake webpacker:install:coffee           # Install everything needed for Coffee
rake webpacker:install:elm              # Install everything needed for Elm
rake webpacker:install:erb              # Install everything needed for Erb
rake webpacker:install:react            # Install everything needed for React
rake webpacker:install:stimulus         # Install everything needed for Stimulus
rake webpacker:install:svelte           # Install everything needed for Svelte
rake webpacker:install:typescript       # Install everything needed for Typescript
rake webpacker:install:vue              # Install everything needed for Vue
rake webpacker:verify_install           # Verifies if Webpacker is installed
rake webpacker:yarn_install             # Support for older Rails versions
rake yarn:install                       # Install all JavaScript dependencies as specified via Yarn
rake zeitwerk:check                     # Checks project structure for Zeitwerk compatibility
```

Comment: What is the output of `rake --tasks` ? What version of rails/ruby are you using ?

Comment: I forgot to add that, sorry. Updated the initial description.

Comment: I just discovered that `rake routes` was deprecated on rails 6.1 in favor of `rails routes`: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/41ad613e4c5d6c05f20ac0437564ff0d31ab9f5a

Comment: @cobexa can you add that as answer to your question

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I just discovered that `rake routes` were deprecated on rails 6.1 in favor of `rails routes`: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/41ad613e4c5d6c05f20ac0437564ff0d31ab9f5a

Comment: This is going to be an incredibly hard habit to break.  I've been writing `rake routes` since about 2009.

Comment: "deprecated" would imply that it still works... bummer they broke it so quickly.

Comment: Yeah, and they added default routes that are so long in terminal that the entire output from the command is illegible on my 15" screen. (>ლ)

Comment: @mindtonic you can use the `--expanded` option for a clean output on your small screen ;-)

Answer (score 7):

`bin/rake routes` is deprecated. You can Use `bin/rails routes`

Answer (score 6):

You can try using rails routes instead of rake routes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `rails routes --expanded` for a very clean output even on small screens.