# RoR command "rake routes" aborts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm taking a class in Ruby on Rails. I just started my first real project and get an error when I try to run:

`$ rake routes`

```
Error:
Don't know how to build task 'routes' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

If I do  `$ rake --tasks`  'routes' is not listed!

I'm using ruby version 2.7.3 and rails 6.1.4

I've looked and looked online, but can't find anything.

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
  get 'home/about'
end
```

Comment: reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65375391/dont-know-how-to-build-task-routes

Comment: For all: the link says `rake routes` is deprecated. Use `rails routes`  @LamPhan  Thank you so much!  This post did not come up when I searched for this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rails routes --expanded`

`rake routes` is deprecated.